# Version for mysql connector, Dialect and mysql server version are not being compatible for mysql 8.0 version

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to connect to mysql server, but unable to. There is some weird error coming up. Logs are present as below

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
currency_exchange  | 2023-06-13T20:06:18.957Z DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
currency_exchange  |
currency_exchange  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
currency_exchange  |
currency_exchange  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
currency_exchange  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
```

I am using the latest version of Spring boot 3.1.0, mysql connector of 8.0.32 in pom.xml, mysql as 8.0, and below is the configuration for application.yaml

```
  database configuration
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-service:3306/currency_exchange_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  # jpa configuration
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

I know issue is with the versions of these, which versions would work perfect, please let me know. Stuck from 2 days.

Comment: did you try  `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with versions etc. you simply cannot connect to the database. Make sure it is active and accesible. Also is this at startup or after some time of running your application?

Comment: Got the solution, running the latest version of mysql with spring is not working. I just downgraded the spring version and it worked. Voila..!!! I wasted 2 days on this..